# Centos 7 curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error

Tags: curl, centos7, php-curl

I've tried to send a `GET` request to a website running `HTTPS` but always getting `curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error.` and I get this error with this only website, Youtube, Google and other sites work fine. Here is information in curl verbose mode.

```
# curl -v https://***.vn > test.htm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   
  Trying 103.x.x.x:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ***.vn (103.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: none
* loaded libnssckbi.so
* NSS error -12188 (SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT)
* Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
```

I'm looking almost every similar question but can't find any solution like:

[AMB Ask about his error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107851/how-to-fix-curl-35-cannot-communicate-securely-with-peer-no-common-encryptio) and solved by ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256 but doesn't work for me.

[Ecluniam having this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228495/php-curl-error-35-peer-reports-it-experienced-an-internal-error) too but it doesn't work for me too

**My curl version**

```
# curl -V
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libpsl/0.7.0 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.31.1
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

I also run `yum update nss nss-util nss-sysinit nss-tools` to the latest nss version still not make it works.

**My openssl version**

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Any idea?